# How would I save and retrieve a boolean into a file using NSData

Tags: iphone, persistence, boolean, nsdata, cocoa-design-patterns

I want to save a boolean into a file and also I want to know how you would retrieve it again. I mainly want to use this for when the iPhone terminates and finishes launching in their respected methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative to manually saving to a file is to use NSUserDefaults.

To save:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:myBool forKey:@"myBool"];
```

To load:

```
myBool = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"myBool"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a boolean to an NSNumber using the convenience constructor (class method) [numberWithBool:](http://17.254.2.129/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000178-numberWithBool_).

NSNumber can be persisted by adding it to an NSDictionary and using [writeToFile:atomically:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000140-CBHDBHDB) to save the dictionary as a property list (plist).

NSNumber objects are also used to represent and persist booleans (as well as integers and floats, but not currency) in Core Data.

Answer (score 0):

You could save it as an integer (1 / 0 = true / false)?

Comment: Yes, but how do I save an integer using NSData or at least into a file. That is what I am asking